# How secure is SharePoint Server 2019 compared to 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, security, 2019

I'm actually in a small battle to propose SharePoint 2019 to my company. They want to go to 2016 as migration from 2013 will be "faster" (skipping the upgrade hop).
I know that I can make myself heard if I come with some improved security features that are on 2019 but not on 2016.
Besides smtp authentication, I am not finding much information.

Do you know if there is an interesting security point I can raise ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2016 is already out of mainstream support. This means you will not receive any improvements/updates to the product itself, only security updates via the [extended support](https://learn.microsoft.com/lifecycle/policies/fixed#extended-support).

[Extended support ends for SharePoint 2016 in July 2026](https://learn.microsoft.com/lifecycle/products/sharepoint-server-2016), which probably leaves your organisation with around 3 years on the platform max before they would have to migrate again (giving the time to move to it and get off the platform before security updates run out). It simply doesn't make sense to choose SharePoint 2016 over SharePoint 2019 from a security or a business perspective. It would be much better to move to SharePoint 2019, safe in the knowledge that you won't have to go through another expensive migration in less than 3 years time when 2019 can be used for many years to come.

There is also the argument for moving to [SharePoint Server Subscription Edition](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/sharepoint-server-subscription-edition-general-availability/ba-p/2913714) rather than SharePoint 2019, since it has [continuous updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/what-s-new/new-and-improved-features-in-sharepoint-server-subscription-edition) and removes the need for costly upgrades from time to time since all the latest innovations are delivered through updates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have anything else to add about the security features, because 19 compared to 16 in my opinion is the enhancement of UI experience and some minor function updates, as well as Microsoft's business support for SharePoint2019 mentioned by Callum. Other than that, the only thing worth mentioning for the company is the 50% increase in the file storage limit in the document library (if that is required).